# Assigning MS CRM task to someone else from Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dynamics-crm

What is the correct way to assign a MS 2011 CRM task to someone else in the company?

Trying to do it from Outlook add-on just pop-ups the regular Outlook tasks window, which, if assigned to someone, does not appear in CRM.

The only way seems to open the Account in browser, and assign the task via activities there, but this seems a cumbersome method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and select the Task in Outlook. On the Ribbon click "View in CRM" to open the CRM copy of the Task (in a separate window) then assign it from there.

Answer (score 2):

First, Find and select the Task in Outlook. Then, on the Ribbon click "View in CRM" to open the CRM copy of the Task (in a separate window) then assign it from there.

Comment: Nice one! Can I create the task directly in CRM straight from Outlook, without creating it first as you suggested?