# Can I assign a task in MS CRM to someone who does not have Outlook synched with CRM

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, dynamics-crm

I'm wondering if it is possible for us to assign a task in MS CRM to another employee who has a CRM User id but does not have the CRM/Outlook Synch plug in installed? We have MS CRM 2011 and MS Outlook 2013.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning MS CRM task to someone else from Outlook?](http://superuser.com/questions/499939/assigning-ms-crm-task-to-someone-else-from-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each Outlook record has a matching CRM record. So they will receive a task, it will just be surfaced inside CRM.

Edit:

Oh, you want the task to appear in Outlook? Well that's what the Outlook integration is for. *I thought this was a question about how an Outlook and CRM user can work together.*

If you don't want to use the Outlook plugin, you should probably look into the server side synchronisation. This will sync records directly to the users Exchange account which can then be accessed inside their Outlook.

The bottom line is that if you want records from CRM to appear in Outlook you need so use some sort of integration they wont just magically appear because the user is a CRM user.

Suggested reading: [Synchronize data in CRM for Outlook](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/synchronize-data-in-crm-for-outlook.aspx)

Comment: Thanks James! We are testing this and it doesn't seem to work. We set up a task for a user in CRM who doesn't have the outlook integration and they are not receiving the task in their outlook. Any thoughts on where we should look to troubleshoot?